# Is the reference voltage for voltage control the RMS between the three phase voltages?

Tags: voltage, avr, generator, rms, power-grid

Suppose to provide voltage control with an AVR connected to a synchronous generator. A voltage reference is compared with the output terminal voltage of the generator, and the error between them is sent to a controller.
My doubt is: since we are in three-phase system, which is the terminal voltage to take from the generator terminal? Is that the average between the RMS of the 3 phases? We cannot measure just one phase and consider it I suppose..

Comment: How are you going to control the voltage? Do you have only one actuating variable or three? If there is only one you can't get controlled voltage on all three phases. Please clarify what you mean with "voltage control" in that 3-phase context.

Comment: AVR measure the terminal voltage of the generator. in three phase system, it measures 3 voltages (of the three phases). From these three voltages just one is taken (this is the problem, I suppose the average between the three but I would know the answer) and is subtracted to a reference voltage. This error is sent to a controller which adjust the excitation of the generator. The voltage is controlled adjusting the excitation of the generator (just one variable).

Comment: Does this system actually exist or is this a hypothetical question? Such a control system would probably work just fine if only one or (better) an average value of the three phases is used as feedback. There is no way around the problem that you need at least one actuating variable per control variable. If there is an unacceptable deviation between those three voltages, all the controller can do is to enter an error state (and eventually shut down the system). It's impossible to stabilize all three voltages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [they](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82BsoaVKKBw) only use 1 phase for feedback to control the AVR field winding current.

[image]